# Can anybody help me understanding this prolog program?

Tags: prolog

```
maxi([X],X).

maxi([K|R],X):- maxi(R,X), X > K.

maxi([K|R],K):- maxi(R,X), X =< K.

?- maxi([4,5,3,8,2],X), write(X).
```

So the output of the program is 8, which is correct, but I don't understand how it works. Can anybody just shortly explain each step of the program?
Would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate expresses:

***maxi(List,X)* is *true* if *X* is the maximum (numeric) element in *List***

And so we have three cases:

- `maxi([X],X).`: The maximum of a one-element list is the element itself. Certainly true.
- `maxi([K|R],X) :- ...` The maximum of the 1-or-more element list `[K|R]` is `X` (rather than K) if:

  - `maxi(R,X)`: the maximum of the tail `R` of the original list is `X` and
  - `X > K`: `X` is actually larger than the head `K` of the original list.
- `maxi([K|R],K) :- ...` The converse of the case above: The maximum of the 1-or-more element list `[K|R]` is `K` (rather than `X`) if:

  - `maxi(R,X)`: the maximum of the tail `R` of the original list is `X` and
  - `X =< K`: `X` is actually smaller or equal than the head `K` of the original list. As an alternative to the `=<` here, one could use `<` and have a third clause for equality: `maxi([K|R],K):- maxi(R,K).` but one doesn't have to.

The above *declarative description* allows the Prolog Processor to consider a list that shrinks by 1 on each recursive call to maxi/2 until a list of length 1 is reached.

This explanation hides information about the precise ordering of the recursive calls, in other words what the lower-level operations are that lead to a concrete result.

This is actually hard to explain clearly in text. Do you know about the Byrd Box model?

Stepping through the debugger (`trace` instruction) may help. On the other, debugger output is not entirely clear. Another possibility is to entomb the program in print instructions, but this is only a one off-solution:

```
maxi(Depth,[X],X) :-
   format("Clause 0, depth ~d: maxi[~q],~q~n",[Depth,X,X]).

maxi(Depth,[K|R],X):- 
   format("Clause 1, depth ~d: maxi[~q|~q],~q~n",[Depth,K,R,X]),
   rider("Clause 1, depth ~d: before recursive call",[Depth]),
   DepthP is Depth+1,
   maxi(DepthP,R,X), 
   rider("Clause 1, depth ~d: after recursive call, before test",[Depth]),
   format("Clause 1, depth ~d: test: ~q > ~q~n",[Depth,X,K]),   
   X > K.

maxi(Depth,[K|R],K):-
   format("Clause 2, depth ~d: maxi[~q|~q],~q~n",[Depth,K,R,K]),
   rider("Clause 2, depth ~d: before recursive call",[Depth]),
   DepthP is Depth+1,
   maxi(DepthP,R,X),
   rider("Clause 2, depth ~d: after recursive call, before test",[Depth]),
   format("Clause 2, depth ~d: test: ~q <= ~q~n",[Depth,X,K]),   
   X =< K.
   
rider(Text,List) :-
   format(Text,List),
   format(", going forward ~n",[]).
   
rider(Text,List) :-
   format(Text,List),
   format(", going backward ~n",[]),
   fail.
```

But at least it gives a discussable trace showing the "rider" moving forwards or backwards for each "predicate activation" (basically, in each stack frame)

```
?- maxi(0,[4,5,3,8,2],X).
Clause 1, depth 0: maxi[4|[5,3,8,2]],_7982
Clause 1, depth 0: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 1: maxi[5|[3,8,2]],_7982
Clause 1, depth 1: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 2: maxi[3|[8,2]],_7982
Clause 1, depth 2: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 3: maxi[8|[2]],_7982
Clause 1, depth 3: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 0, depth 4: maxi[2],2
Clause 1, depth 3: after recursive call, before test, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 3: test: 2 > 8
Clause 1, depth 3: after recursive call, before test, going backward 
Clause 1, depth 4: maxi[2|[]],_7982
Clause 1, depth 4: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 4: before recursive call, going backward 
Clause 2, depth 4: maxi[2|[]],2
Clause 2, depth 4: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 2, depth 4: before recursive call, going backward 
Clause 1, depth 3: before recursive call, going backward 
Clause 2, depth 3: maxi[8|[2]],8
Clause 2, depth 3: before recursive call, going forward 
Clause 0, depth 4: maxi[2],2
Clause 2, depth 3: after recursive call, before test, going forward 
Clause 2, depth 3: test: 2 <= 8
Clause 1, depth 2: after recursive call, before test, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 2: test: 8 > 3
Clause 1, depth 1: after recursive call, before test, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 1: test: 8 > 5
Clause 1, depth 0: after recursive call, before test, going forward 
Clause 1, depth 0: test: 8 > 4
X = 8
```

You need to be more precise in what you know.

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
maxi([X],X).
maxi([K|R],X) :- maxi(R,X), X > K.
maxi([K|R],K) :- maxi(R,X), X =< K.
```

The way to understand `maxi([4,5,3,8,2],X)` is to first start from the simplest case, and then try the more involved ones, building your understanding along the way.

So what is the result of querying `maxi([], Y)`? It is, according to the three clauses of `maxi`'s definition,

```
maxi([],Y)
==>
  maxi([], Y) = maxi([X],X)    ,  true                    %%  first clause 
; maxi([], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K        %%  second clause 
; maxi([], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K       %%  third clause 
==>
fail
```

isn't it? And what is the result of querying `maxi([2],Y)`? It is

```
maxi([2],Y)
==>
  maxi([2], Y) = maxi([X],X)    ,  true
; maxi([2], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  [2]=[X],   Y=X
; [2]=[K|R], Y=X                ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; [2]=[K|R], Y=K                ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  X=2,       Y=X
; K=2,       Y=X                ,  maxi([],X), X > K      %%  ***
; K=2,       Y=K                ,  maxi([],X), X =< K     %% 
==>
             Y=2
;                                  fail                   %%  as seen before
;                                  fail                   %%
==>
             Y=2
```

right? And `maxi([8,2],Y)` is

```
maxi([8,2],Y)
==>
  maxi([8,2], Y) = maxi([X],X)    ,  true
; maxi([8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  [8,2]=[X],   Y=X
; [8,2]=[K|R], Y=X                ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; [8,2]=[K|R], Y=K                ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
               Y=X                ,  maxi([2],X), X > 8        %%  ***
;              Y=8                ,  maxi([2],X), X =< 8       %%
==>
               Y=X                ,  X=2        , X > 8        %%  as seen before
;              Y=8                ,  X=2        , X =< 8       %%  
==>
               Y=8        %% the second alternative is chosen
```

And `maxi([3,8,2],Y)`:

```
maxi([3,8,2],Y)
==>
  maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([X],X)    ,  true
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  [3,8,2]=[X], Y=X                  ,  true
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],X)  ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
  [3,8,2]=[K|R], Y=X                ,  maxi(R,X), X > K
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
                 Y=X                ,  maxi([8,2],X), X > 3    %% seen above
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
                 Y=X                ,  X=8,           X > 3
; maxi([3,8,2], Y) = maxi([K|R],K)  ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
                 Y=8
; [3,8,2]=[K|R], Y=K                ,  maxi(R,X), X =< K
==>
                 Y=8
; 3=K,           Y=K                ,  maxi([8,2],X), X =< K   %% and again,
==>
                 Y=8
;                Y=3                ,  X=8,           X =< 3
==>
                 Y=8        %% the first alternative is chosen
```

We can see from this that in general, the code could be made a bit clearer as

```
maxi([X],Y) :- Y=X.
maxi([K|R],Y) :- maxi(R,X), X > K, Y=X.
maxi([K|R],Y) :- maxi(R,X), X =< K, Y=K.
```

or

```
maxi([X],Y) :- Y=X.
maxi([K|R],Y) :- maxi(R,X), (X > K, Y=X ; X =< K, Y=K).
```

or even

```
maxi([X],Y) :- Y=X.
maxi([K|R],Y) :- maxi(R,X), (X > K -> Y=X ; Y=K).
```

since the arithmetic comparison, `X > K`, means that the predicate's first argument must always be fully known (a.k.a. ground) anyway.

And so the meaning of the predicate is:

- for a singleton list `[X]`, its maximum is `X`
- for a non-empty list `[K|R]`, its maximum is
- - `X`, if the maximum of `R`, `X`, satisfies `X > K`, *or*
- - `K`, otherwise

which makes sense indeed.